# Strange regex behavior

Tags: init-file, regular-expressions, cursor

I want to skip blank region under cursor, so I created this regex:

`\s+\w` translated to emacs regex `[:space:]+[:graph:]` but it doesnt match what I want. It matches some random space somewhere!

Whats even worse, regex `[:space:]\{1,\}[:graph:]` which is exactly same fails completelly without giving me anything.

What I want concretelly:

[cursor]_____some code...

I want to get position of the code to be able to jump there with cursor ...

EDIT:
CODE

(trying to enhance code of someone else, just to be clear ...)

```
(setq custom/separators-regexp
      (concat "\\([\-'\"(){};:,.\\/?!@#%&*+=\]\\)\\|\\(\\[\\)\\|"
              "\\(\\]\\)\\|\\(\\s-\\)\\|\\(\\s_\\)\\|\\(\\`\\)\\|"
              "\\(\\'\\)\\|\\(\\^\\)\\|\\(\n\\)"))

(defun custom/position-normalize-forward (saved-pos my-pos)
  "Normalize position after forward move"
  (if (>= (- my-pos saved-pos) 2)
      (progn
                                        ;going to my-pos
        (goto-char my-pos)
        (if (not (eq my-pos (point-max)))
            (progn
                                        ;also backward-to-separator to fix position
              (custom/backward-symbol))))
    (progn
                                        ;going to my-pos in the usual way
      (goto-char my-pos))))

(defun custom/forward-symbol ()
  "Move to the next separator like in the every NORMAL editor"
  (interactive "^")
  (let ((saved-pos (point))
        (my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
        (my-pos2 (re-search-forward "[:space:]+[:graph:]")))
    (if (> my-pos2 my-pos)
        (progn
          (message "POS %s %s" my-pos2 my-pos)
          (goto-char my-pos2)
          (return)))
    (if (eq my-pos 1)
        (progn
          (goto-char (+ my-pos 1))
          (setf my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
          (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos))
      (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos))))
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Change the regexp-string to `"[[:space:]]+[[:graph:]]"`.

Comment: It helped, but it is extremelly agressive, I want to anchor it somewhat, but ^ not wors as I want. Is there some cursor-wise anchor ?

Comment: `\=` (or in a double-quoted string, `"\\="`) matches the empty string at point. Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Backslash`

Comment: Works for me: moves to the first occurrence, starting at point, of at least one whitespace char followed by a graphic character. 

`(re-search-forward "[[:space:]]+[[:graph:]]")` is not particularly "aggressive", nor does it just match "some random space somewhere!" And it searches from point (cursor position) forward ("anchored" at point). 

It's likely the rest of your code that is problematic, not the regexp.

Comment: Also, you might find that your monster `custom/separators-regexp` could be reduced to `"\\([]['\"(){};:,.\\/?!@#%&*+=^[:space:]\n-]\\|\\s_\\|\\\`\\|‌​\\'\\)"`, assuming most of the groupings are as redundant as I suspect they are.

Comment: Use `looking-at` instead of `re-search-forward` to anchor the search at point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your help. Emacs is extremelly hard to dive in alone.

Solution with `\\=` partially worked well (with another checks because regex sometimes jumped somewhere ... even after usage of `\\=`). It was looking bright but, ... backward regex checking simply does not worked. After I tried to reverse regex and play with it, I simply give up. Emacs regex handling is simply outside of my league.

So I used simple while loop to find blank space ...

This is resulting and working code:

```
(require 'cl-macs)

(setq custom/separators-regexp
      "\\([]['\"(){};:,.\\/?!@#%&*+=^[:space:]\n-]\\|\\s_\\|\\`\\|‌​‌​\\'\\)")

(defun custom/position-normalize-forward (saved-pos my-pos)
  (if (>= (- my-pos saved-pos) 2)
      (progn
        (goto-char my-pos)
        (if (not (eq my-pos (point-max)))
            (progn
              (custom/backward-symbol))))
    (progn
      (goto-char my-pos))))

(defun custom/forward-symbol ()
  (interactive "^")
  (block custom/forward-symbol
    (let* ((saved-pos (point))
           (my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
           (my-pos2 (custom/find-blank-space t saved-pos)))
      (if (> my-pos2 my-pos)
          (progn
            (goto-char (- my-pos2 1))
            (return-from custom/forward-symbol)))
      (if (eq my-pos 1)
          (progn
            (goto-char (+ my-pos 1))
            (setf my-pos (re-search-forward custom/separators-regexp))
            (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos))
        (custom/position-normalize-forward saved-pos my-pos)))))


(defun custom/position-normalize-backward (saved-pos my-pos)
  (if (>= (- saved-pos my-pos) 2)
      (progn
        (goto-char my-pos)
        (if (not (eq my-pos 1))
            (progn
              (custom/forward-symbol))))
    (progn
      (goto-char my-pos))))

(defun custom/backward-symbol ()
  (interactive "^")
  (block custom/backward-symbol
    (let* ((saved-pos (point))
           (my-pos (re-search-backward custom/separators-regexp))
           (my-pos2 (custom/find-blank-space nil saved-pos)))
      (if (< my-pos2 my-pos)
          (progn
            (goto-char (+ my-pos2 1))
            (return-from custom/backward-symbol)))
      (if (eq my-pos (point-max))
          (progn
            (goto-char (- my-pos 1))
            (setf my-pos (re-search-backward custom/separators-regexp))
            (custom/position-normalize-backward saved-pos my-pos))
        (custom/position-normalize-backward saved-pos my-pos)))))

(defun custom/find-blank-space (go-forward starting-pos)
  (let ((starting-char (string (char-after starting-pos)))
        (skipped-count 0)
        (increment (if go-forward 1 -1))
        (should-loop t))
    (if (or (equal starting-char " ")
            (equal starting-char "\t")
            (equal starting-char "\n"))
        (progn
          (while should-loop
            (if (or (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) " ")
                    (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) "\t")
                    (equal (string (char-after (+ saved-pos skipped-count))) "\n"))
                (setq skipped-count (+ skipped-count increment))
              (setq should-loop nil)))
          (+ starting-pos skipped-count))
      starting-pos)))
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as answered.